# How to get request body from ServerRequest object in Spring WebFlux reactive?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

Trying to extract the body of a POST request sent using Postman to my Spring application.
I've tried doing
`ServerRequest.bodyToMono(String.class).toProducer().peek()`  but that returns null.

`ServerRequest.bodyToMono(String.class).block()` isn't supported anymore.

Also tried doing it this way:

```
      Mono<String> bodyData = request.bodyToMono(String.class);

      System.out.println("\nsubscribing to the Mono.....");

      bodyData.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newParallel("requestBody")).subscribe(value -> {
        log.debug(String.format("%n value consumed: %s" ,value));
      });
```

But I can't seem to get anything to show up in the logs.

Comment: In what context is this code used? Is this a http endpoint you're are testing?

Comment: Something like that. I'm trying to capture the request body so I can cache it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an example of a reactive rest endpoint that just stores the body in some cache the following example should achieve this

```
public class Example implements HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> {

    private final CacheService cache;
    
    @Override
    public Mono<ServerResponse> handle(ServerRequest request) {
        return request.bodyToMono(String.class)
                .doOnNext(body -> cache.put(body))
                .flatMap(body -> ServerResponse.noContent().build());
    }
}
```

Comment: finally you got me